# Custom Field в Django

Tags: django, django-model

Изучаю джанго и нашел пример в документации как можно создать собственное поле для модели. Проблема в том, что данный пример не работает(вылетает глупая ошибка nonetype object has no attribute 'north'). Все бы ничего, но с учетом того, что я только изучаю данный фреймворк, я не могу понять, в чем проблема(вылетает в методе get_prep_value()). Код приведен ниже:

```
def parse_hand(hand_string):
    p1 = re.compile('.{26}')
    p2 = re.compile('..')
    args = [p2.findall(x) for x in p1.findall(hand_string)]
    if len(args) != 4:
         raise ValidationError(_("Invalid input for a Hand instance"))
    return Hand(*args)
class Hand:

    def __init__(self, north, east, south, west):
        self.north = north
        self.east = east
        self.south = south
        self.west = west

    def __str__(self):
        return self.north

class HandField(models.Field):

    description = 'A hand of cards'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        del kwargs["max_length"]
    return name, path, args, kwargs

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return parse_hand(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Hand):
            return value
        if value is None:
        return value

        return parse_hand(value)

    #вот тут ошибка
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return ''.join([''.join(l) for l in (value.north,
                                         value.east, value.south, value.west)])
```

Модель:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    hand = HandField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Функция `get_prep_value` обязана уметь обрабатывать ситуацию, когда значение отсутствует, то есть когда `value` имеет значение `None`. В данном случае вам, вероятно, достаточно написать `if value is None: return None`